# Is there an element-free proof that preimages of radical ideals are radical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, radicals

Suppose we have a ring homomorphism $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ and an ideal $J\subseteq B$.

I just spent way too much time on an exercise in commutative algebra, because the element-free definition of the radical of $J$ as
$$\sqrt{J} = \bigcap \limits_{q\in \operatorname{Spec}B, J\subseteq q} q$$
suggested to me that there might be a discrepancy between
$$\phi^{-1}(\sqrt{J}) = \bigcap \limits_{q \in \operatorname{Spec} B, J \subseteq q} \phi^{-1}(q)$$
and
$$\sqrt{\phi^{-1}(J)} = \bigcap \limits_{p\in \operatorname{Spec} A, \phi^{-1}(J)\subseteq p} p$$
(the latter intersection appears to be smaller in total)

But using the element-wise definition of a radical in terms of powers one can deduce that both sets always coincide! So I am wondering, whether I should have noticed it somehow while working with the element-free definition…

Comment: Well, the intersection definitely has more intersecting ideals. Consider $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, and $J=(0)$. The only prime ideal of $B$ that contains $J$ is $(0)$, but *every* prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ contains $\phi^{-1}(J)$. So you can certainly have fewer ideals of the form $\phi^{-1}(q)$, $q\in\mathrm{Spec}((B)$, $J\subseteq q$ than ideals of the form $p\in\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, $\phi^{-1}(J)\subseteq p$.

Comment: Yes. And still $f^{-1}(\sqrt{(0)})=\sqrt{f^{-1}((0))}$. I find that surprising… (not this example is surprising, but that the identity holds in general)

Comment: I think the key is that any ideal $p$ that does not "come" from an ideal $q$ contains one that does, so that they don't actually matter in the intersection.

Comment: By factoring through $A/\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$, you can assume that $\phi$ is an embedding (the result holds for surjections, by the correspondence theorem).  So then you only need to verify that for every prime of $A$ containing $J\cap A$ there is a prime $q$ of $B$ with $J\subseteq q$ and $q\cap A\subseteq p$.

Comment: The reduction certainly works and I can see how we could finish in the setting of an integral extension, but I am unable to close the general case. Why should such a prime $q$ exist? Are you considering minimal prime ideals containing the set $J$? But then why should such a thing intersected with $A$ be contained in $p$?